# PIC18f4550 / LCD16x2 / MIKRO C

Tags: pic, lcd

I have a simple question that is stopping me.

This program runs whit out an error, it increases "x" and show the result in the display, but...

```
// LCD module connections
sbit LCD_RS at RD4_bit;
sbit LCD_EN at RD5_bit;
sbit LCD_D4 at RD0_bit;
sbit LCD_D5 at RD1_bit;
sbit LCD_D6 at RD2_bit;
sbit LCD_D7 at RD3_bit;

sbit LCD_RS_Direction at TRISD4_bit;
sbit LCD_EN_Direction at TRISD5_bit;
sbit LCD_D4_Direction at TRISD0_bit;
sbit LCD_D5_Direction at TRISD1_bit;
sbit LCD_D6_Direction at TRISD2_bit;
sbit LCD_D7_Direction at TRISD3_bit;

void main(){
 int x = 0;
 char txt[255];
 Lcd_Init();
 Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CURSOR_OFF);
 Lcd_Out(1, 1, "Total:");
 Lcd_Out(2, 1, "$");

while(1){
     IntToStr(x, txt);
     Lcd_Out(2, 11, txt);
     x++;
     Delay_ms(100);
 }
}
```

When i add the configuration code in order to have 4 inputs in PORTA:

```
// LCD module connections
sbit LCD_RS at RD4_bit;
sbit LCD_EN at RD5_bit;
sbit LCD_D4 at RD0_bit;
sbit LCD_D5 at RD1_bit;
sbit LCD_D6 at RD2_bit;
sbit LCD_D7 at RD3_bit;

sbit LCD_RS_Direction at TRISD4_bit;
sbit LCD_EN_Direction at TRISD5_bit;
sbit LCD_D4_Direction at TRISD0_bit;
sbit LCD_D5_Direction at TRISD1_bit;
sbit LCD_D6_Direction at TRISD2_bit;
sbit LCD_D7_Direction at TRISD3_bit;

void main(){
 TRISA = 0B00001111;
 CMCON = 0B00000111;
 ADCON1 = 0X0F;
 PORTA = 0;
 int x = 0;
 char txt[255];
 Lcd_Init();
 Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CURSOR_OFF);
 Lcd_Out(1, 1, "Total:");
 Lcd_Out(2, 1, "$");

while(1){
     IntToStr(x, txt);
     Lcd_Out(2, 11, txt);
     x++;
     Delay_ms(100);
 }
}
```

appears the follow error:

Invalid expression in line "int x = 0;"

Please, help!

Comment: ' CMCON = 0B00000111:' <-- should end in a ';' not a ':'.

Comment: Thank you brhans but I made that mistake here, not in the development tool, the error still appears

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Your C compiler is old and crusty

Early C (K&R) had a rule where all variable declarations in a block must come before all other statements in a block, and this rule wasn't lifted until ISO C99.  So, you need to move the declarations of `x` and `txt` above the statements before them to make things work with your compiler, which clearly predates ISO C99 (it's C90-vintage, at best).